# Normalization of panel data [IV regression]

Tags: regression, normalization, standardization, instrumental-variables

I have panel data which contains ~80 countries over the period of last 15 years. I want to investigate how chosen regressors (e.g. number of patents) affect economic growth. Taking into account that my panel has strong heterogeneity (contains very poor and rich countries) I decided to perform standardization of the data (Z-score normalization, i.e. subtract the mean and divide by the standard deviation) in order to make my data (countries) more comparable.

Using standardization rather than normalization outliers still remain in data (high values). The `betas` would be estimated via Instrumental Regression to control endogeneity problem (some variables seem to be correlated with error term). Negative effects of autocorrelation and heteroskedasticity would be treated by using robust Newey-West standard errors. Rank of matrix (whether it is full or multicollinearity exists) would be controlled via Variance Inflation Factor.

I have some unresolved issues:

1) Should I standardize each country separately or all countries together within one variable (whole column).

2) If dependence between certain variables is non-linear could I use 2nd degree polynomial or logarithmic transformation of standardized variables to make this dependence more linear?

P.S. I don't want to use other techiques such as simultaneous equations to estimate coefficients, and I also will not make any predictions. I just want to know how certain regressors affect dependent variable.

I would be appreciated if you provide references for scientific papers.

Comment: On the last, any good econometrics text will give many references. On #1 what would standardisation for each country mean? The only standardisation that makes obvious sense here is for each variable (which isn't necessary at all).

Comment: #2 is easy. You could transform variables. From the nature of your data it could well be a good idea, but nothing more can be said specifically on this description.

Comment: @NickCox "for each country mean" means that I want standardize data for each country within each variable, i.e. standardize  GDP (acros 15 years) for France, Poland, Germany etc. separately. On the other hand, standardizing GDP for all countries at once (not separately) GDP of poor countries such as Afghanistan would be affected by richest countries.

Comment: @NickCox You also said that "The only standardisation that makes obvious sense here is for each variable (which isn't necessary at all)" . Does it mean that there is no sense to standardize variables, and why?

Comment: Thanks for the extra detail. I think I see what you mean about different countries and the answer there is what makes sense substantively (economically). Otherwise I am not a fan of standardization as (1) $t$ and $P-$ values scale for different units of measurement any way (2) I often want to see coefficients in units I understand directly, but that boils down to personal taste.